# Как с помощью метода re.findall() узнать начальную и конечную точку вхождения строки

Tags: python-3.x

Нужно получить, вместо массива строк, начальный id и конечный id подстроки
Пример:

```
>>> import re
>>> result = re.findall(r"значение","много текста значение много текста")
>>> print(result)
['значение']
```

А нужно получить начальный и конечный id подстроки, аналогично методам re.match.start() и re.match.end()

Comment: Используйте `finditer` вместо `findall`, он возвращает итератор из match-объектов, в каждом из которых хранится индекс начала и конца совпадения.

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено, спасибо человеку под ником insolor.
Ниже приведена функция.

```
def findstr(myStr,findStr):
    result = re.finditer(findStr,myStr)
    for i in result:
        print(i.start())
        print(i.end())
```